# set options in scope of a `source`ed script

Tags: bash

I'm writing a shell script that sets enviornment variables. It will be sourced in other scripts like

```
source /path/to/my-script
```

I want my script to use `set -euo pipefail` but I don't want to affect the calling script.

This will affect the calling script.

```
# my-script
set -euo pipefail # affects the caller
export VAR=$(get-value)
```

If I wrap my script in a subshell the export won't work

```
# my-script
(
  set -euo pipefail
  export VAR=$(get-value) # not exported to the caller
)
```

Comment: The point of the `source` command is to include a file in the sourcing script AS THOUGH it had always been part of the sourcing script. It is not really correct to refer to the 2 scripts as the 'caller' and 'called', as there is no 'calling' happening. Sub-shells cannot change the environment of their parents. What you should do is set the options at the start of the source script and unset them (`set +...`) at the end.

Comment: `set +e` may _unset_ an option if the caller (or sourcer if you prefer) had `set -e`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if a file is sourced it is done to include all its parameters, so if you want to source a file partially, a workaround may be to exclude those parameters that you don't need and create a new temporary file with the rest of the parameters and eventually source the new file and delete it.

For your scenario, this workaround will do the job, use the following lines in your `caller-script.sh` to create `my-script.tmp` file from `my-script` file with **lines** starting with `set` excluded, source the `my-script.tmp` file and then remove it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
grep -wv '^set' my-script > /tmp/my-script.tmp
source /tmp/my-script.tmp
rm /tmp/my-script.tmp
```